# SOAP PHP Request

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to turn this example request into PHP SOAP functions. This is what support told me for this soap server that I needed. I barely have any SOAP experience and I can't figure out how to structure this in PHP.

```
<CreateCustomerRequest xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BillingTree.ApiService.Contract" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <MerchantCredentials>
        <CertId></CertId>
        <Password></Password>
        <UserName></UserName>
        <Zid></Zid>
    </MerchantCredentials>
    <Customer>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine1></AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2 i:nil="true"/>
            <AddressLine3 i:nil="true"/>
            <City>Los Angeles</City>
            <Country>USA</Country>
            <Province i:nil="true"/>
            <State>CA</State>
            <ZipCode>85284</ZipCode>
        </Address>
        <Department></Department>
        <Email></Email>
        <Fax i:nil="true"/>
        <FirstName></FirstName>
        <Id></Id>
        <LastName></LastName>
        <Phone></Phone>
        <Status>Active</Status>
        <Title></Title>
    </Customer>
</CreateCustomerRequest>
```

Comment: You should really make some attempt before asking for help. If you _have_ made an attempt, show what you tried.

Comment: I have tried all kinds of things. Nothing has really gotten close.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to SOAP, then you should try using a WSDL to PHP generator that will ease you the SOAP request construction. You can try the project [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) so you'll end up with a full PHP SDK of the SOAP Web Service and a tutorial file as a starting guide.

Answer (score 0):

```
< ? php
// $client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/php/soap/math.wsdl');
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost/php/soap/soap_server.php? WSDL");
try{
  $result = $client->div(8, 2);
  print "The answer is: $result";
}catch(SoapFault $e){
  print "Sorry an error was caught executing your request: {$e->getMessage()}";
}
?>
```

you can use like this ,a very basic example